# Python: ChromeDriverManager chrome downloads from incorrect url of latest chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

My log shows that the Chromedriver downloads from a 3 part version number rather than a 4-part

```
10:32:22 INFO About to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112/chromedriver_win32.zip
```

It should be
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/chromedriver_win32.zip

(i.e have the 4th part of version)

Ive tried setting the latest_release_url to a 4 part version number but it doesnt overwrite it. Code below

```
        full_version = '104.0.5112.79'
        caps = {"pageLoadStrategy": "normal"}
        latest_release_url = 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/{LATEST_RELEASE}_{full_version}'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            ChromeDriverManager(
                latest_release_url=latest_release_url).install(),
            options=options,
            desired_capabilities=caps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in which [os](/questions/tagged/os) variant/flavor or specific circumstances or *Python* version you are seeing the shortened download url as:

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112/chromedriver_win32.zip
```

---

However, on my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) *64-bit operating system, x64-based processor* system using using [webdrivermanager-python](/questions/tagged/webdrivermanager-python) ***v3.5.2***, [python](/questions/tagged/python) ***v3.9.0***, [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) ***v4.4.0*** and the following line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

I can properly see the *full path* i.e.

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/chromedriver_win32.zip
```

within the logs:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 104.0.5112
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 104.0.5112 google-chrome
There is no [win32] chromedriver for browser  in cache
Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/chromedriver_win32.zip
Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\username\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\104.0.5112.79]
```

---

### Update

Though as per [selenium/py/CHANGES](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/CHANGES) page ***Selenium 4.4.2*** is the latest release but may be not be stable.

To be on the safer side ideally we need to use the version mentioned in the [Downloads](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) webpage, which is ***v4.4.0***

Comment: Python 3.8.0 in my case. Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Selenium version?

Comment: Checkout eh versioning info in the updated answer.

Comment: Selenium 4.4.2  is the version there

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: @Ray Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: WebDriverManager version please?

Comment: Thanks just got some higher prio work but will get back